# Make a field readonly in edit mode and editable in create mode in openerp

Tags: xml, openerp-7

I want to make a field readonly in edit mode and editable in create mode in openerp. I want a field for which value is specified while creating and later it should not be changed.

This is my code:

```
<field name = "apply_to_future" class="oe_edit_only"  attrs="{'readonly':[('status','=','Draft')]}" />
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
attrs="{'readonly':[('apply_to_future','!=',False)]}"
```